# EF - Cascade Delete Not Working, Can't Delete Object

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException The DELETE statement conflicted
>   with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_*comments*_postId__164452B1". The
>   conflict occurred in database "awe", table "dbo.comments", column
>   'postId'. The statement has been terminated.

I have this structure:

```
    public class Post
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }     

        public long? ParentId { get; set; }
        public virtual Post Parent { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    }

    public class Comment
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public long PostId { get; set; }
        public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
    }
```

my delete method:

```
    public void Delete(long id)
    {
        var p = context.Set<Post>().Get(id);
        if(p == null) throw new MyEx("this post doesn't exist");
        if (p.Posts.Count > 0) throw new MyEx("this post has children and it cannot be  deleted");
        context.Set<Post>().Remove(p);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

my DbContext:

```
public class Db : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It sounds like the Post that you are trying to delete has child Comments.

Entity Framework will not take responsibility for cascading a delete in the database – it expects that you will achieve this by setting a cascading delete on the foreign key relationship in the RDBMS.

Having said this, if you delete a parent entity in Entity Framework, it will attempt to issue delete statements for any child entities which have been loaded into the current DbContext, **but it will not initialize any child entities which have not yet been loaded**. This may lead to the RDBMS throwing foreign key constraint violation exceptions if a cascading delete has not been specified, like the one you are seeing. For more details about how cascade delete “works” in Entity Framework, [see this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/08/19/tip-33-how-cascade-delete-really-works-in-ef.aspx) *(alas, dead link as of 2023-04-03)*.

Comment: The link is dead.